# Android Room Auto Migration for new column not working

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

I have searched stackoverflow for a similar question and none has been found, other possible solutions for different cases did not work for me either. I am opening this question seeing that I cannot find a solution for this problem, nor can I find a similar question for this problem.

---

I've tried to use Android Room's auto migration feature, but it never works correctly.

The current scenario is as follows:

I have a Database version 1

I want to add a new column to one table, that is the only modification I want to do. This column will be holding String values and nothing else.

This new column will only exist in Database version 2

I have set up the Database as per the Android documentation

When I run the app again (an app with a database version 1 populated with data) the app crashes

The crash error in the console is this:

```
2021-08-24 21:35:53.941 3081-3141/com.app.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-18-thread-2
    Process: com.app.test, PID: 3081
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: My(com.com.app.test.data.datbase.entity.MyEntity).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='My', columns=long list of column definitions}
     Found:
2021-08-24 21:35:53.942 3081-3141/com.app.test E/AndroidRuntime: TableInfo{name='My', columns=long list of column definitions, plus the new one}
```

I have setup the database with the new version number (2), and set export schema to true, and defined the automigrations from 1 to 2.

I also defined the schemaLocation in the app gradle configuration options.

I cannot find anywhere explained why this is not working, it is a simple operation of adding a new column to an existing table.

Does anyone know why this isn't working and how can I get it to work without having to write the migration manually?

EDIT: Upon closer inspection it seems that there is some issue with the defaultValue definition in the database migration.

The expected shows the column with a default value that is not null, this is correct
`defaultValue=''NOT_NOTIFIED''`

The found shows it is null, this is incorrect
`defaultValue='NULL'`

The column definition for that entity is as follows

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "notified", defaultValue = "NOT_NOTIFIED")
public String notified = "NOT_NOTIFIED";
```

But somehow it is generating a definition or migration where the default value is null, instead of what I am setting it to.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue lately, and for me, the issue was that I forgot about a manual migration I've written a while ago that had the same version numbers.

This might not be your case, but for me to figure out why I was getting the wrong migration, I set a breakpoint at the `onUpgrade` method at `RoomOpenHelper.java` which led me to the forgotten manual migration. so give it a try it might provide you with more information on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `defaultValue` from the column definition in the entity itself appears to do the trick, but it is a requirement to have a default value for that column. This does not appear to be a proper behavior, but a bug somewhere in the auto migration logic.

Hoping someone might have a clue of what is going on and come up with a proper solution that is not to remove the `defaultValue` definition.

Comment: `defaultValue` can only be of use if you use an `@Query("INSERT INTO (<csv of column names>) VALUES(<csv list of values that match the columns>)` **WHERE** the column to use the default value **IS NOT** one of the columns to be inserted into. Using @Insert will insert a null into the column and thus the default value is not applied. As per *Table columns that do not appear in the column list are populated with the default column value (specified as part of the CREATE TABLE statement), or with NULL if no default value is specified.* https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: Ooops forgot the table name for the INSERT INTO. Should be `@Query("INSERT INTO <the table name> (<csv of column names>) VALUES(<csv list of values that match the columns>)`

Comment: @MikeT I am not doing any `@Query` whatsoever, this is literally Android's full AutoMigration, I am not doing anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the columnInfo name and default value did the trick for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31312093)